# problem of bean injection RabbitTemplate in Junit with spring-boot 2

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, junit4

I have small problems, injection of a bean when I run in spring-boot everything works well but with Junit. I have an example with RabbitTemplate

```
 public class NettyServerRun {

    @Autowired
    private IDeviceClient deviceClientComponent;
    @Autowired
    private ServiceDeviceServer service;

    @Autowired
    private RabbitManager mqService;

    private int port = 7650;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() throws InterruptedException {
        NioEventLoopGroup boosGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        NioEventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        ServerBootstrap bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap();
        bootstrap.group(boosGroup, workerGroup);
        bootstrap.channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class);
        final EventExecutorGroup group = new DefaultEventExecutorGroup(1500); 
        bootstrap.childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
        @Override
        protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
        ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();
        pipeline.addLast(workerGroup,new 
        RequestDecoderServer(deviceClientComponent)); 
        pipeline.addLast(workerGroup,new ResponseEncoderServer()); 
        pipeline.addLast(group,new AuthenticateHandler(service));
        pipeline.addLast(group,new CommandResponseHandler(service));
        pipeline.addLast(group,new DeviceDataHandler(mqService));
    }
        });
        ChannelFuture f = bootstrap.bind(port).sync();
        f.channel().closeFuture().sync();
    }
```

```
    @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
    @DataJpaTest
    @Import(NettyServerRun.class)
    @AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace=Replace.ANY)
    @ComponentScan("com.metier")
    public abstract class DeviceServerTest {

    @Autowired
    protected TestEntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    protected ServiceDeviceServer service;

    @Autowired
    protected TestRestTemplate template;


    protected DeviceServerContext context;
    protected Gson gson;
    protected Nmea nmeaData;

    @Value("${spring.profiles.active}")
    private String activeProfile;


    protected void persistList(List<AbstractEntity> list) {
        list.forEach(entity -> entityManager.persist(entity));
    }

    public GpsCmdRsp buidGpsCmdRsp(Long gpsId) {
        GpsCmdRsp reference = new GpsCmdRsp();
        reference.setCommand("*TS01,188765,NAM#");
        reference.setCompletedAt(buildHier());
        reference.setGpsId(gpsId);
        reference.setResponse("*TS01,353836057694499,013809281017,NAM:ODO50- 
        BLE#");
        reference.setSuccess(false);
        return reference;
     }
```

```
  public class DeviceDataHandlerTest extends DeviceServerTest {

    @Autowired
    private NettyServerRun nettyServerRun;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {

    }

    @Test
    public void channelReadDeviceExistTest() {
        String[] trame = {
             "*TS01,351579056605817,003410140618,GPS:3;N46.758156;W71.134046;6;0;0.96,STT:c003;8001,MGR:957975,SAT:43;40;39#" };
        EmbeddedChannel channel = new EmbeddedChannel(new DeviceDataHandler());
        boolean ok = channel.writeInbound(trame);
        assertThat(ok).isTrue();

    }

}
```

Error log

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1654) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1213) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1167) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
... 44 common frames omitted ##
```

So,Like I said . if I run just with with Spring-Boot, the RabbitTemplate injection work fine . But , if a run with Junit.  I try to add  @SpringBootTest

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Configuration error: several statements found from @BootstrapWith for test class [com.AuthenticateHandlerTest]: [@ org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapWith (value = class org.springframework.boot.tocon. test.autoconfigure.orm .jpa.DataJpaTestContextBootstrapper), @ org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapWith (value = class org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper)]
at org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils.resolveExplicitTestContextBootstrapper (BootstrapUtils.java:166)
org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils.resolveTestContextBootstrapper (BootstrapUtils.java:127).
```

Because of @DataJpaTest

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I had to mock the bean that uses RabbitTemplate.

Put this annotation at the top of your test's class name:

```
@MockBean(RabbitManager.class)
```

For anyone else, the class will be the one that contains the RabbitTemplate field, i.e.:

```
@MockBean(MyServiceContainingRabbitTemplate.class)
```

But that leads me to question why I had to do this. I would like to know :)

Answer (score 0):

The `@DataJpaTest` annotation in your test uses to scan `@Entity`, repositories, `EntityManager` and other necessary beans for working with a database in tests, but this annotation does not load regular `@Component` beans into the `ApplicationContext`.

In your test case, you can use the `@SpringBootTest` annotation instead of the  `@DataJpaTest` to load the entire application context.